# Can this distribution be expressed as a known distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this density function

$$f_{\theta}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{x^{2} \theta} e^{-\frac{1}{\theta x}} & \text { if } x \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text { other case }\end{array}\right.$$

Im trying to express it as a known distribution as i want to make some calculus on probabilites. I tried with a exponential and gamma distribution but with no results, dont know what more to try. Any help would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an [inverse-gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) with $\alpha=1,\,\beta=1/\theta$.